# Get image from response android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a web app that returns me an image in the response body. Now I have something like this but I have

> not found okhttp3 responsebody

```
App.getApi().getUserPicture(id,token).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

How can I get this image?
P.S I am using Retrofit 2.
Thanks

Comment: make a model for your response instead, it will solve everything

Comment: and get your response in that, parse it the way you want to, to make it a bitmap.

Comment: Thank you. I've already solved this problem